# Checking if some transformations are linear or not

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Check if the transformations below are linear:
$$
f : R^3  \rightarrow R : f(x,y,z) = x + 5y - z \\
g : R^3  \rightarrow R : f(x,y,z) = x + 5y - z + 1\\
h : R^3  \rightarrow R : f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 5y - z  \\
$$

My answer:

For any transformation being linear, it must have the following properties:
$$
f(\vec{a}+\vec{b}) = f(\vec{a}) + f(\vec{b})\\
f(c\vec{a}) = c\cdot f(\vec{a})
$$Now what I should do is check if these properties can be applied to the transformations:

For the first one:
$$
f(a+d,b+e,c+f) = a+d+5(b+e)-(c+f)\\
f(a,b,c) + f(d,e,f) = a+5b-c+d+5e-f = \\a+d+5(b+e)-(c+f)\\
\text{1º property: OK}
$$
$$
f(x(a,b,c)) = f(xa,xb,xc) = xa+5xb+xc = x(a+5b+c)\\
\text{2º property: OK}
$$
For the second one:
$$
f(x(a,b,c)) = f(xa,xb,xc) = xa+5xb-xc+1 \\
x\cdot f(a,b,c) = x(a+5b-c+1)=xa+5xb-xc+x\\
f(x(a,b,c)) \neq x\cdot f(a,b,c)\\
\text{2º property: NOT OK}
$$
For the third one:
$$
f(x(a,b,c)) = f(xa,xb,xc) = (xa)^2 + 5xb - xc\\
x\cdot f(a,b,c) = x(a^2+5b-c) = x(a)^2 + 5xb - xc\\
f(x(a,b,c)) \neq x\cdot f(a,b,c)\\
\text{2º property: NOT OK}
$$

Concluding that just the transformation $f$ is linear.

Is there an easier way to get to the answer faster? What I've done is correct? I'm still learning linear algebra... sorry for the newbie question. Ty

Comment: Your answer is correct and could hardly be made shorter *and* formal. Just change that "above" for "below"

Comment: Ohh haha, thanks! I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all correct.  There are some shortcuts which can be easily derived from the definitions, such as f(0)=0 for a linear transformation (this works for the second one).  Other than that, you could try specific counterexamples to show one is not a linear transformation--(for the last one, try $h(1,0,0)+h(2,0,0) \neq h(3,0,0)$.  To show it is in fact a linear transform, there is no shorter way.

Comment: Counterexamples... Thank you!!